# Spring security redirect to login form with Java based configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to configure a Java-based Spring Security redirect to a login page for any request that is not authenticated and currently have the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity security) throws Exception {
        security
                .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**")
                ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ;

    }
}
```

In the class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer` I have the following:

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
rootContext.register(SecurityConfig.class);
container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
```

Setting a breakpoint within the `configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)` method shows that the method is called on startup, but no request is redirected to `/login`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question for others with a similar problem. The solution was to add a new empty class extending `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` as follows:

```
public class SecurityApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    // Nothing
}
```